# How to find $\sup \Pi_{i=0}^{n} (\sin(i)^2 - \frac{25}{16})$?

Tags: trigonometry, limsup-and-liminf, products

Let $\sup,\inf,{\rm dif}$ denote resp supremum , infimum and $\rm dif$ = supremum - infimum.

Does any of the 3 below have a closed form ?

$\sup \Pi_{i=0}^{n} (\sin(i)^2 - \frac{25}{16})$

$\inf \Pi_{i=0}^{n} (\sin(i)^2 - \frac{25}{16})$

${\rm dif} \Pi_{i=0}^{n} (\sin(i)^2 - \frac{25}{16})$

Comment: Is your dummy variable $i$ used at all?

Comment: Oh sorry. edited. Thanks Jeff.

Comment: no included efforts to solve this, therefore downvote.

Comment: By $\sup / \inf$, do you mean $\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ / $\inf\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ or some thing like that?

Comment: @achille yes exactly. Although if we used a continu product that would give the same result. ( this might confuse Some , srr ). Maybe you or myself should edit.

Comment: Dif = 0 by symmetry !! Sup = 1,66785193... Apparantly.

Comment: Symmetry from $( sin(i) - 5/4 )(sin(i) + 5/4 ) = sin^2(i) - 25/16 )$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer. Let:

$$A_n := \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( \sin^2 (k)-\frac{25}{16} \right),$$

and:

$$F(x) := \ln \left( \frac{5}{4}-\sin(x) \right).$$

Then:

$$\ln (A_n) = (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(F(k)+F(-k)\right).$$

Now, $F$ has integral $0$ (this comes from the choice of the constant $5/4$), and is analytic. In addition, $1/\pi$ has a finite irrationality measure. Hence, $F$ is a coboundary for the translation by $1$ on $\mathbb{R}_{/2\pi\mathbb{Z}}$. More precisely, we can solve the equation:

$$F(x) = g(x+1)-g(x),$$

with $g(0)=0$. Taking the Fourier coefficients, we get, for $\xi \neq 0$:

$$\hat{g} (\xi) = \frac{\hat{F} (\xi)}{e^{i\xi}-1},$$

whence:

$$g(x) = \sum_{\substack{\xi \in \mathbb{Z} \\ \xi \neq 0}} \hat{F} (\xi) \frac{e^{i\xi x}-1}{e^{i\xi}-1}.$$

Going back to our initial problem, we get:

$$\ln (A_n) = (-1)^n (g(n)+g(-n)).$$

The translation by $1$ is uniquely ergodic on $\mathbb{R}_{/2\pi\mathbb{Z}}$. Better, the translation by $(1,1)$ is uniquely ergodic on $\mathbb{R}_{/2\pi\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{/2\mathbb{Z}}$, so that we don't have to worry about the sign. Hence,

$$-\ln(\inf_n A_n) = \ln(\sup_n A_n) = \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}_{/2\pi\mathbb{Z}}} |g(x)+g(-x)| = 2 \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}_{/2\pi\mathbb{Z}}} \left| \sum_{\substack{\xi \in \mathbb{Z} \\ \xi \neq 0}} \hat{F} (\xi) \frac{1-\cos(\xi x)}{1-e^{i\xi}}\right|.$$

Disclaimer : sign errors may be hidden somewhere.

Comment: I think this can be improved. I had similar ideas. Neef to consider it again. +1 anyways.