# Fourier coefficients of $\ln(K-\sin(x))$

Tags: fourier-series, trigonometric-integrals

Let $K \geq 1$ be a real number. What are the Fourier coefficients of the function

$$\ln (K-\sin(x))$$

As it is a [follow-up from this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553888/how-to-find-sup-pi-i-0n-sini2-frac2516/2064990#2064990), I am especially interested in the case $K = 5/4$ (for which the constant term is $0$), but I guess that computing these coefficients for all values of $K$ is of similar difficulty.

Note that I know how to compute any given coefficient, as it can be reduced to integrals of trigonometric rational functions. What I lack is a general formula for all coefficients.